# Eigen Vectors Concept: Proving

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A matrix **G** has eigen vector **e** How can i prove that **e** is also an eigen vector for **G**+*k* **I** where **I** is an identity matrix. (they are all 3x3). I tried using A**e** = *k* **e**  i didnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just applying the definition one has

$$(\mathbf{G}+k\mathbf{I})v=\lambda v+k v=(\lambda+k)v$$

Which means $v$ is an eigenvector of $\mathbf{G}+k\mathbf{I}$ associated to the eigenvalue $\lambda+k$